# Append the nested case statement content with outer case statement's content using perl

Tags: perl

In this situation we have to deal with nested case statements, which you can observe by seeing the input file and output.
     **INPUT FILE**

```
case name in      
   ABSI) one="1"     
         two="2"    
    ;;    
   DEV)                 
        one="11"       
         two="22"       

           case nest in    
              kmr) three="3"
               ;;
              sug) four="4"
                   five="5"
                case next_level in

                      CAC)six="6"
                      ;;
                  esac
              ;;
            esac
      ;;

   DUL) seven="7"  
         nine="9"  
           case again in  

            NOV) six="66"
                      ten="10"
                  ;;
               esac
        ;;
esac
```

**OUTPUT SHOULD BE **

```
ABSI:one="1"  
ABSI:two="2"  
DEV:one="11"  
DEV:two="22"  
DEV:kmr:three="3"  
DEV:sug:four="4"  
DEV:sug:five="5"  
DEV:sug:CAC:six="6"  
DUL:seven="7"  
DUL:nine="9"  
DUL:NOV:six="66"  
DUL:NOV:ten="10"
```

---

I got the output for one level nested case statement. first I saved the content between first "case" and last "esac" (same as "end") in a temp file and run the below given script

```
 open (data,"<input.txt");  
while (<data>) {  
$para1;  $para2;    
  unless (/case/../esac/){  
      if(/(.*)\)(.*)$/) {  
    $para1=$1;  
     $var=$2;         
     }  
     else  {  $var=$_; }  
print $para1.$var."\n";  
}  
   if (/case/../esac/)  {  
        if(/(.*)\)(.*)$/) {  
       $para2=$1;    
       $var=$2;         
       }  
      else  {  $var=$_; }          
print $para1.$para2.$var."\n";  
}   }  
close data;
```

I need your help and suggestion to get output for multiple nested case statement.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an array containing the current levels. Push another level onto it whenever you see a `xxx)` line and pop the latest one off when you see a `;;` line. Then you just need to look for the assignment statements.

This seems to work for your test data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
# We use modern Perl here - specifically say()
use 5.010;

my @levels;

while (<DATA>) {
  if (/(\w+)\)/) {
    push @levels, $1;
  }
  if (/(\w+="\w+")/) {
    say join(':', @levels), ":$1";
  }
  if (/;;/) {
    pop @levels;
  }
}

__DATA__
case name in
   ABSI) one="1"
         two="2"
    ;;
   DEV)
        one="11"
         two="22"

           case nest in
              kmr) three="3"
               ;;
              sug) four="4"
                   five="5"
                case next_level in

                      CAC)six="6"
                      ;;
                  esac
              ;;
            esac
      ;;

   DUL) seven="7"
         nine="9"
           case again in

            NOV) six="66"
                      ten="10"
                  ;;
               esac
        ;;
esac
```

The output is:

```
ABSI:one="1"
ABSI:two="2"
DEV:one="11"
DEV:two="22"
DEV:kmr:three="3"
DEV:sug:four="4"
DEV:sug:five="5"
DEV:sug:CAC:six="6"
DUL:seven="7"
DUL:nine="9"
DUL:NOV:six="66"
DUL:NOV:ten="10"
```

Comment: Hi Dave, i am getting syntax error at line 12 , near "say join".

Comment: i am running this script using putty and version is v4.8.4.

Comment: Have you included the `use 5.010` line? And which version of Perl are you using?

Comment: The version of putty isn't very useful information. The version of Perl is.

Comment: here it is showing version 5.8.4  .So i used "use v5.8.4". But  i am getting syntax error at line 12.

Comment: Perl 5.8.4 was released in 2004. Why on Earth would you use a version of Perl that is over twelve years old? I added the `use 5.010` line specifically because I use syntax that only became available in Perl 5.10. If you want to run my code on older versions of Perl then you will need to replace `say` with `print`.