# how to substitute actual value of variable in a file which is present in another file in perl

Tags: perl

I have two file.Variables are declared in first file($one=1;) , in second file variable name is given ($one). I want to substitute this variable name with actual value and print the output.
**File1.txt**

```
 variables are gieven here
    $one=1;
    $name="gorge";
    $animal="cat";
```

**File2.txt**

```
This number is x=$one/or less then two  
his name is $name  
It is a $animal/ kind of animal.
```

**Expected output**

```
This number is x=1/or less then two  
    his name is gorge  
    It is a cat/ kind of animal.
```

I tried with this code:

```
open (data1,"</home/file1");
open (data2,"</home/file2");
while (<data1>){
     while (<data2>){
       print $_;
  }
}
close data2;
close data1;
```

Thank You.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or something else? Because you're skirting around the edges of something really filthy, when there's a much better solution.

Comment: I gave here a test data. i have to substitue the actual value of the variable from environment  file.

Comment: I started perl scripting 20 days before because of requirement .So please help me with a better solution. thank you

Comment: You didn't answer the question about whether this was homework. When you say you started to learn Perl "because of requirement" is this a college requirement or something for work? Can I also remind you that you haven't accepted an answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153700/append-the-nested-case-statement-content-with-outer-case-statements-content-usi). If you don't respond to the answers you get, people will start to ignore you.

Comment: @jhulan: At present we urgently need to know how your `File1.txt` and `File2.txt` have been created, or perhaps will be created in the application's ultimate context. Withholding information like that is suspicious and weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're fishing for something that is a [horribly bad idea](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html).

So I'll suggest a different approach, of building regular expressions to replace the text. In doing this though - the use of `$one` is going to be a bit confusing, because that means a scalar variable in perl, and this is "just" going to be a pattern match.

So if you can change that - you should:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %replace = ( 'one' => '1',
                'name' => 'gorge',
                'animal' => 'cat' ); 

my $search = join ( '|', keys %replace ); 
   $search = qr/\$($search)/;

print Dumper \%replace;
print $search;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/$search/$replace{$1}/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
This number is x=$one/or less then two  
his name is $name  
It is a $animal/ kind of animal.
```

You can build your `replace` patterns something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %replace = map { m/\$(\w+)=\"?([^;\"]+)/ } <DATA>;

print Dumper \%replace;

__DATA__
    $one=1;
    $name="gorge";
    $animal="cat";
```

This gives you:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'name' => 'gorge',
          'one' => '1',
          'animal' => 'cat'
        };
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a *templating system*

One of the most popular ones is [***Template Toolkit***](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template)

For example, with this template file

#### File2.template

```
This number is x=[% one %]/or less then two  
his name is [% name %]  
It is a [% animal %]/kind of animal.
```

And this Perl code

#### main.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Template;

my $tt = Template->new;

my $vars = {
    one    => 1,
    name   => 'gorge',
    animal => 'cat',
};


$tt->process('File2.template', $vars);
```

The result is this

#### output

```
This number is x=1/or less then two  
his name is gorge  
It is a cat/kind of animal.
```

Comment: Hi Borodin , In actual file there are multiple lines. Could you please explain

Comment: how to get "File2.template"  and "$vars" for big file. Thank you.

Comment: jhulan:You must explain the background. Do you have existing files that were created for a different templating system? Do you need to create them from scratch? Is this just an idea that your boss has told you to go with? My answer will solve your problem, but I have tried to avoid awkward the constructions that [***Sobrique*** has described](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40302659/622310). Please explain where your `File1.txt` and `File2.txt` came from?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be any kind of Perl programmer, then you'll need to read the [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html).

In there, you'll find an answer to your question.

- [How can I expand variables in a text string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings%3F)

If you read that answer, you'll end up with code very similar to [what Sobrique gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40302659/7231). However, in order to get to that code, you'll need to first pass the first paragraph in the answer which says:

> If you can avoid it, don't, or if you can use a templating system, such as [Text::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template) or [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template), do that instead.

That's really good advice. You should follow it.